# How to add a complex object to model of each angular-formy type when validated?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-formly

Say I have a custom angular-formly type that extends a input type.
Lets call it user.

Before the form gets filled in model = {}.

Once its filled in and valid, I would like to have this result

```
model = {
    user:{
        name:"TestName" //The value of the input
        someCustomData: "Not part of the form"
        someMoreMetaData: "Also not part of the from"
    }
}
```

The resulting model having appended arbitrary meta-data once user entered a valid name. Thus creating a "user specific model"

So basically, I want my validation function to push the result to the model.

How would I approach this, for the key has to be bound to a property of a object that will only exist once validation returns true.

```
{
    key: //what do I bind to?
    type: 'USER',
    templateOptions: {
        required: true,
        type: 'text'
    },
    validators:{
        isValid: function($viewValue, $modelValue, scope){
           var value = $modelValue || $viewValue;
           if (validateName(value)){
              scope.model.user = { name: viewValue, date:....}
              return true;
           }
        }
    }
```

}

If possible, please nudge me in the right direction..Still pretty novice.

Comment: Can you share some code, what do you currently have?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$scope.user
   {
        'name':'TestName', 
        'someCustomData': 'Not part of the form',
        'someMoreMetaData': 'Also not part of the from'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a watch validation and act when valid:

```
scope.$watch('myForm.myInput.$valid', function(validity) {$scope.user.custom data ="blabla"})
```